# Java: Timezone random display name for UTC / GMT+0

Tags: java, timezone

we currently have the problem that we get different display names for the same timezone in JAVA.

The code:

```
TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName();
```

I have two machines running in UTC:
On the one machine I get "Greenwich Zeit" and on the other machine I get "Koordinierte Universalzeit".

I used the code from http://sanjaal.com/java/462/java-date-time-calendar/how-to-get-all-supported-timzone-ids-display-name-and-gmt-offset/ to get a list of all timezone IDs and their displaynames and offsets. Below you see an excerpt which only shows the GMT+0 results.

Java for some reason seems to pick a name randomly for this timezone (TimeZone.getDefault())

**Question:** Is there a way to always get the same consistent display name?

```
Africa/Accra                    :Ghanaische Normalzeit                                 GMT+0:0
Africa/Bamako                   :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/Banjul                   :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/Bissau                   :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/Casablanca               :Westeuropäische Zeit                                  GMT+0:0
Africa/Conakry                  :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/Dakar                    :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/El_Aaiun                 :Westeuropäische Zeit                                  GMT+0:0
Africa/Freetown                 :Greenwich Normalzeit                                  GMT+0:0
Africa/Lome                     :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/Monrovia                 :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/Nouakchott               :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/Ouagadougou              :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/Sao_Tome                 :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Africa/Timbuktu                 :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
America/Danmarkshavn            :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Atlantic/Canary                 :Westeuropäische Sommerzeit                            GMT+0:0
Atlantic/Faeroe                 :Westeuropäische Sommerzeit                            GMT+0:0
Atlantic/Faroe                  :Westeuropäische Sommerzeit                            GMT+0:0
Atlantic/Madeira                :Westeuropäische Sommerzeit                            GMT+0:0
Atlantic/Reykjavik              :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Atlantic/St_Helena              :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Eire                            :Irische Sommerzeit                                    GMT+0:0
Etc/GMT                         :GMT+00:00                                             GMT+0:0
Etc/GMT+0                       :GMT+00:00                                             GMT+0:0
Etc/GMT-0                       :GMT+00:00                                             GMT+0:0
Etc/GMT0                        :GMT+00:00                                             GMT+0:0
Etc/Greenwich                   :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Etc/UCT                         :Koordinierte Universalzeit                            GMT+0:0
Etc/UTC                         :Koordinierte Universalzeit                            GMT+0:0
Etc/Universal                   :Koordinierte Universalzeit                            GMT+0:0
Etc/Zulu                        :Koordinierte Universalzeit                            GMT+0:0
Europe/Belfast                  :Britische Sommerzeit                                  GMT+0:0
Europe/Dublin                   :Irische Sommerzeit                                    GMT+0:0
Europe/Guernsey                 :Britische Sommerzeit                                  GMT+0:0
Europe/Isle_of_Man              :Britische Sommerzeit                                  GMT+0:0
Europe/Jersey                   :Britische Sommerzeit                                  GMT+0:0
Europe/Lisbon                   :Westeuropäische Sommerzeit                            GMT+0:0
Europe/London                   :Britische Sommerzeit                                  GMT+0:0
GB                              :Britische Sommerzeit                                  GMT+0:0
GB-Eire                         :Britische Sommerzeit                                  GMT+0:0
GMT                             :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
GMT0                            :GMT+00:00                                             GMT+0:0
Greenwich                       :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Iceland                         :Greenwich Zeit                                        GMT+0:0
Portugal                        :Westeuropäische Sommerzeit                            GMT+0:0
UCT                             :Koordinierte Universalzeit                            GMT+0:0
UTC                             :Koordinierte Universalzeit                            GMT+0:0
Universal                       :Koordinierte Universalzeit                            GMT+0:0
WET                             :Westeuropäische Sommerzeit                            GMT+0:0
Zulu                            :Koordinierte Universalzeit   

                     GMT+0:0
```

Answer (score 2):

JAVA picks up the Time zone on the basis of the `LOCALE`.

The `Locale` in the two machines would be different and therefore the difference.

A possible solution can be to create a `Locale` object and pass it to your method like - `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(localeObject);`

The `Locale` object can be created as follows -

```
Locale(String language)
Locale(String language, String country)
Locale(String language, String country, String variant)
```